# should I use amazon cloud server for android app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am developing an app that will run in the way that presents restaurant menus and have like buttons for each dish. I am thinking of storing the menus and uses data on amazon cloud server. Any better solutions? If using cloud server, how to access the data in my android app? Implementing sort of web service? or is able to access like querying a remote database?

Comment: Use Google App engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download aws sdk for Android here: http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdkforandroid/

From api you can access all amazon services, an easy way to start is by using SimpleDB to store your data, probably free tier will solve your problem.
But I strongly recomend an Android cache for offline access to your app, which can be built up using SQLite.